# react-native, these properties are not compatible with android: autoCorrect and secureTextEntry

Tags: android, react-native

These two properties of `TextInput` are not compatible with android:

- `autoCorrect`
- `secureTextEntry`

I run into following error while I have autoCorrect:

> Error while updating property 'autoCorrect' of a view managed by: AndroidTextInput

I run into following error while I have secureTextEntry:

> Error while updating property 'password' of a view managed by: AndroidTextInput

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

here is my code:

```
<Text style={styles.text}>{text.Email}</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Image style={externalStyles.styles.iconImage} resizeMode="contain" source={externalImags.Images.emailIcon} />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
                value={this.state.email}
                keyboardType="email-address"
                placeholder={text.email}
                autoCorrect="false"
                clearButtonMode="always"/>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.text}>{text.Password}</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Image style={externalStyles.styles.iconImage} resizeMode="contain" source={externalImags.Images.passwordIon} />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                value={this.state.password}
                keyboardType="default"
                placeholder={text.password}
                autoCorrect="false"
                secureTextEntry="ture"
                clearButtonMode="always"/>
            </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using autoCorrect={false}

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem.

`autoCorrect="false"`  will work on iOS, but not Android.

It needs to be `autoCorrect={"false"}`  for Android.

I've found React-Native iOS forgiving with some "bad habit syntax", Android is not.

You should be using `autoCorrect={'false'}` for both.  Always put props in `{}`

Comment: Thank you!
Actually, I need to put it in {} but without quotes, 
like: 
autoCorrect={false}
secureTextEntry={true}
It fixed the problem.